# Nothing happened for the first time when i changed the checkbox by ng-change()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to check the checkbox input state when the user click it.
But when i clicked it on the first time nothing happened.
So in the second time when i click it again the function that i put in ng-change() works fine.

Am i missing something?

```
<tr dir-paginate="product in kitchenProducts | itemsPerPage: 10">
  <td>
    <img ng-src="{{ product.images.full_size }}" class="table-thumbnail-product" alt="">
  </td>
  <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
  <td>Sandwitch</td>
  <td>{{ product.price }}</td>
  <td>
    <label class="toggle toggle-balanced">
      <input type="checkbox" 
             ng-model="productToggleButton" 
             ng-checked="product.is_enabled" 
             ng-change="toggleProductEnable(product.is_enabled,product.id)" value="{{ product.id }}" 
             class="">
      <div class="track">
        <div class="handle"></div>
      </div>
    </label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$scope.toggleProductEnable = function(productSelected, productId) {
  console.log(productId);
  if (productSelected) { //If it is checked
    alert('check');
  } else {
    alert('uncheck');
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> What is you trying to do is simple like here

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mymodel" ng-change="callmyfunction(item.myID)" /> 


$scope.callmyfunction= function (myID) {
   if($scope.mymodel){ //If it is checked
       alert('checked');
   }else{
      alert('not checked test');    
}
}
```

In your case 
remove ng-checked="product.is_enabled"

$scope.toggleProductEnable = function(productSelected, productId) { 
console.log(productId); if ($scope.productToggleButton) { //If it is checked alert('check'); } else { alert('uncheck'); } }

Comment: I need to check that if the checkbox is checked, 
Then do the first function.

But if it unchecked,
Then do the second function.

Comment: remove ng-checked="product.is_enabled"   and try

Comment: $scope.toggleProductEnable = function(productSelected, productId) {
  console.log(productId);
  if ($scope.productToggleButton) { //If it is checked
    alert('check');
  } else {
    alert('uncheck');
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

The check input type has the attribute checked which returns a boolean value checking if the input is checked or not.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="mymodel" ng-change="callmyfunction(item.myID)" class="checkbox"/> 


let checkboxElement = document.querySelector('.checkbox')
if (checkboxElement.checked == true) { alert('checked')} 
else {alert('Not Checked')}
```